# Incorporate javascript into href tag

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, cascadingdropdown

bit clueless when it comes to such things however if anyone can assist i'd be most grateful.

I have a nested css vertical dropdown menu in ms expression web, previously I used the asp.net built-in function to create a dropdown and the following:

```
<select size ="1" name="main10" onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'main')"style="width: 290px">
```

along with some additional code to have the content of the dropdown appear in an iframe AND resize said iframe according to content (i.e. eliminating scrollbars and other nastiness)

However expression does not allow nested dropdowns easily and I am forced to try a different approach.

I need to incorporate the above code into this: `<li><a href="#">Some Text Here</a></li>` many times, with different urls, linking to various pages within the site.

I tried to be as descriptive as possible but i've no doubt missed some sort of vital information so please ask if i'm being unclear.

Comment: Why do you want Javascript?

Comment: HTML doesn't allow nested drop-downs using SELECT, regardless.

Comment: sorry, but what is your actual question?  you described your set up and some things you've tried, but I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: SLake2 - I want Javascript as thats the only way I found to do what i needed. If there's an easy alternative i'd happily use it

Diodeus - the SELECT does not have to be used if there is a workaround

ben336 - I haven't actually suggested anything which i've tried, and the question is how to do I incorporate the javascript which resizes the iframe window according to the page being linked to.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you just want a click on an anchor tag to run some JS. If so, you can do this:

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="your JS here;">Some Text Here</a></li>
```

It would be a good idea to `return false;` from the click handler too, to prevent the default click action, and if you put the desired URL in the `href` attribute the link will still work even for users that have JS disabled. So putting that together with your `window.open`:

```
<li><a href="http://xyz.com" onclick="window.open(this.href,'main');return false;">Some Text Here</a></li>
```

Given you intend to have lots of these links you don't want to be repeating `window.open()` everywhere, so:

```
<li><a href="http://x.com" onclick="return doOpen(this.href);">X Here</a></li>
<li><a href="http://y.com" onclick="return doOpen(this.href);">Y Here</a></li>
<li><a href="http://y.com" onclick="return doOpen(this.href);">Z Here</a></li>

<script>
function doOpen(url) {
    window.open(url, 'main');
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: It works!

Thank you so much, you have no idea how much potential heartache you've spared me!

Comment: Ooh, no it doesn't  quite work properly...

The resulting iframe has a scrollbar which is what I was trying to avoid in the first place

Comment: Why encourage using the `onclick` attribute? I would point the asker towards writing unobtrusive JavaScript...

Comment: You can specify more stuff on the window.open call. The scroll bars can be removed by specifying scrollbars=yes|no|1|0, as specified in W3Schools. Here is the link: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp).

Comment: @user2062729: You should use the `target="main"` attribute instead of Javascript.